# rmagick under windows 7 Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, rmagick

I just wanted to install rmagick under windows.

I installed ImageMagick-6.8.9-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe with C/C++ header in C:\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16. In addition I verified that ImageMagick is installed correctly by running covert logo: logo.gif in cmd.

I installed Ruby Installer in C:\Ruby200-x64

I installed RubyDevKit under C:\rubyDevKit2.02.1x64

Both the rubydevkit and ruby200 are in my environment paths. I also confirmed that I was able to install gems with RubyDevKit.

My gem environment below

```
C:\rubyDevKit2.02.1x64>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
- RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-09-19 patchlevel 576) [x64-mingw32]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200-x64/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x64-mingw32
- GEM PATHS:
 - C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
 - X:/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
```

Error when I try and do a gem install of rmagick

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-dir=C:\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:565:in `try_cpp'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1044:in `block in have_header'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1043:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:186:in `<main>'
```

What is interesting is my mkmf.log

```
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -IC:\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -LC:\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/lib -L.    -lCORE_RL_magick_ -lX11  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
c:/rubydevkit2.02.1x64/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/lib/X11.lib when searching for -lX11
c:/rubydevkit2.02.1x64/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/lib/X11.lib when searching for -lX11
c:/rubydevkit2.02.1x64/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/lib\X11.lib when searching for -lX11
c:/rubydevkit2.02.1x64/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lX11
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

Comment: `skipping incompatible ... when searching for -lX11` generally means that the library you have installed isn't compiled for the right platform. Did you install the MinGW version of ImageMagick and for the right architecture?

Comment: I didn't install MiniGW. Should I be installing this?

Comment: It looks like the RubyDevKit already installed it for you (`c:/rubydevkit2.02.1x64/mingw`).